# How do i turn an object array into a formgroup array?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use the array function of the formbuilder in order to work with formcontrol arrays. I have an existing custom object array that needs to be added to that `FormArray` however it only takes `FormGroup` as arguments. How do I transform my array of custom objects into FormGroup objects so that those can be added into the FormArray? I've already tried this:

```
let formGroupArray: FormGroup[] = [];
    for(let i=0; i < account.laborperiods.length; i++){
      let formGroup = this.fb.group({
        id: this.account.laborperiods[i].id,
        beginDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].beginDate,
        endDate: this.account.laborperiods[i].endDate,
        hours: this.account.laborperiods[i].hours,
        account: this.account.laborperiods[i].account
      })
        formGroupArray.push(formGroup)
    }
    this.laborPeriodArray = new FormArray(formGroupArray);
```

But this is giving me the error `"ERROR TypeError: Circular reference in value argument not supported"`

So can anyone tell me how I convert a custom object array into a FormGroup array? Or maybe there is a more convenient way where the custom object array can be transformed directly into a FormArray?

Comment: I think that must be: let formGroupArray:FormArray=new FormArray();

Comment: I cant instantiate a no-args FormArray. It needs to be instantiated with an abstractControl array (in my case FormGrouparray) as an argument.

Comment: [This example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
let formGroupArray:FormArray
for(let i=0; i < account.laborperiods.length; i++){
      let formGroup = this.fb.group({
          ...
      })
      if (!formGroupArray)
        formGroupArray=new FormArray(formGroup);
      else
        formGroupArray.push(formGroup)
}
//Change this line
this.laborPeriodArray = formGroupArray;
```

Comment: I already tried this: it should be an array of formgroups (or abstractcontrols), so this code gives me an error. However I can instantiate it like this: this.laborPeriodArray = new FormArray([]), in other words by instantiating with an empty array. About the Circular reference error: It was caused by a JSON.stringify console.log codeline, not by the array itself.

Comment: //Change this line
    this.laborPeriodArray = formGroupArray;